# How to get all row from left table multiply for right table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following two tables:

```
  Table: ProductList
  Product;
   Product a
   Procuct b 
   Product c
   ...
   Product Z

Table: SalesTable
Agent, Product, Qty
 ZXY, Product A, 200
 ABC, Product A, 100
 ABC, Product B, 200
```

I would like to have a table with ALL product List * Agent list. 
So, for instnace :

```
   Agent, Product, Qty
   ZXY, Product A, 200
   ZXY, Product B,  -
   ZXY, Product C,  - 
   ....
   ABC, Product A, 100
   ABC, Product B, 200
   ABC, Product C, -
   ABC, Product D, -
```

Using :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ProductTable
       LEFT JOIN AgentTable 
            ON ProductTable.Product = SalesTable.Product
```

not work, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
Select Distinct B.Agent,A.Product,C.Qty

from

Product A

Cross JOIN SalesTable B 

Left join SalesTable C on C.Product=A.Product and C.Agent=B.AGENT
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30335/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Agent, t1.Product, COALESCE(s.Qty, '-') AS Qty
  FROM (
        SELECT a.Agent, p.Product
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Agent FROM SalesTable) a
               CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM ProductList) p
        ) t1 LEFT JOIN SalesTable s
                  ON (t1.Product = s.Product 
                      AND t1.Agent = s.Agent)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this query

```
SELECT ST.*
FROM ProductList PL
JOIN SalesTable ST ON PL.Product = ST.Product
ORDER BY ST.Agent, ST.Product
```

Removed Group By, as order was required and not grouping

SQLFiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30335/18